# how to position wp admin bar with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

im making a WordPress theme from start but im in trouble with WP admin bar default position, here es a screenshot on how it looks now:

[image]

i need to position the wordpress admin bar on the top of my other bar NOT above on my other top bar

something like this

[image]

but i cant seem how to do this.

here is the full code:

codepen.io/ismael158/pen/ZGPMqZ?editors=110

thank you very much!!

Comment: You could always have top: 32px; on your own nav bar. You'd have to have that class appear on it with php whenever the user has a top admin bar. (To avoid having users with no admin bar seeing a margin of 32px at the top)

Comment: @Adam yes it worked!! very fast solution but i cant seem how to apply this class in php only if the user is logged in or is admin and if its a normal user dont use this class, i was thinking of using if(current_user_can("administrator")){ $("#top-navbar").addClass("myCass");}else{$("#top-navbar").removeClass("myCass");} but i dont know where to put the code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you give your menu a fixed position. The code you share is not very useful to help with that, what matters is what surrounds it. But basically WordPress pushes the `<html>` tag down when the toolbar is visible. So, you could solve this by

1. giving the frame that surrounds the menu a relative position,
2. giving your menu an absolute position.

Absolute positioning basically does the same as fixed positioning, but it's relative to the first frame with relative positioning that surrounds it, instead of to the screen.

f.ex.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>[...]</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="top-nav">
            [your menu]
        </div>
        [your content]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.frame {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.top-nav {
    background: blue;
    height: 43px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps. GL with it!